# Using SparkOptimizer for custom optimizations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, sql-optimization

I am trying to plug in a few custom-optimized logical plans into SparkOptimizer and check if they are executed.

I have an object that extends RuleExecutor: xyz.Scala in /spark/sql/catalyst/abc which has 'val batches' with custom batches as shown below:

```
Object xyz extends RuleExecutor{
val batches = Batch (custom rule1):: Batch(custom rule2) :: Batch(custom rule3) :: Nil
}
```

I want these rules to be reflected when I submit an example application to Spark. I read about exerimental.extraOptimizations, but I am not sure how to implement it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The new experimental methods that come with V 2.2.* can be used only if you need custom optimization for a particular application and not for all the applications you submit to spark. In my case, I had to include all the custom batches to optimizer.Optimizer. So the rules are batched with native rules.